# Gson fromJson and toJson for simple object returning null in Java

Tags: java, object, serialization, gson

Greetings I am new here and to Java and would much appreciate your advice.   I am using gson-2.3.1 and when I call either toJson or fromJson I unexpectedly get back null.   I was attempting this on a much more complex object, so I went back to basics with the user guide here https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples .   The code below is almost exactly copied, does compile but doesn't work for me returning the null in both to and from cases.  Only the case with the string literal works. Advice much appreciated, thanks!

```
    //an object
    class BagOfPrimitives {
        private int value1 = 1;
        private String value2 = "abc";
        private transient int value3 = 3;
        BagOfPrimitives() {
            // no-args constructor
        }
    }

    // (Serialization)
    BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
    Gson expgson2 = new Gson();
    String json = expgson2.toJson(obj);
    // here json in null - expected was the string below
    String expectedjson = "{\"value1\":1,\"value2\":\"abc\"}";

    // (Deserialization)
    BagOfPrimitives obj2 = expgson2.fromJson(expectedjson, BagOfPrimitives.class);
    // result is obj2 is null and not the object expected
```

Comment: I don't believe you. Please demonstrate exactly what is `null`.

Comment: Read [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) about Gson's (lack of) support for local classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem.   All of the code above was inside of a method so I was declaring the class BagofPrimitives inside of a class which the compiler did allow so I thought it was okay.  Remember I am new to Java, still learning.  Once I moved BagofPrimitives out to where it belonged the code worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer above by Ocean is correct, I'd like to just say that the problem is with the documentation. Looking at the [guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) it would seem that an inner class for `BagOfPrimitives` is perfectly fine when in reality it's not even supported. Fully working and non-working code given below. Note that both compile with no errors.

## Works

```
package com.mypackage;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

class BagOfPrimitives {
  private int value1 = 1;
  private String value2 = "abc";
  private transient int value3 = 3;

  BagOfPrimitives() {
  }
}

public class Trials {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(obj);
    System.out.println(json);
  }
}
```

#### Output

```
{"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}
```

## Doesn't work:

```
package com.mypackage;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Trials {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    class BagOfPrimitives {

      private int value1 = 1;
      private String value2 = "abc";
      private transient int value3 = 3;

      BagOfPrimitives() {
      }
    }

    BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(obj);
    System.out.println(json);
  }
}
```

#### Output

```
null
```